# Gettiing an evisa for Turkey when already have confirmed return ticket from France via Turkey

Tags: visas, schengen

While returning from France I will be having connecting flight from Turkey to Pakistan on Turkish airline so with same date of arrival at and departure from Turkey on ticket.
Can I apply for evisa for stop over before going to France and once I get the evisa I get the modified return ticket of the date after number of days I wish to stop over in Turkey.

Answer (score 2):

An itinerary or ticket is asked for when applying for the Turkish e-Visa:

> [Visa Information For Foreigners](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)
>
> • The Electronic Visa (e-Visa) Application System was launched on 17 April 2013 by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Republic of Turkey. This system allows visitors travelling to Turkey to easily obtain their e-Visas online (www.evisa.gov.tr), in approximately three minutes.
>
> It is possible to obtain e-Visa 7/24 at everywhere with internet connection. The applicants can obtain their visa after they fill in the necessary information concerning their identity, passport and travel dates and pay visa fee online.

The above link lists country-by-country requirements, exemptions, and permitted lengths of stay.